# Bottom Border Looks like wave

Tags: html, css, styles

I am looking to make the bottom of a navigation div have a wave. Similar to the attached image. [image]

Answer (score 0):

you may want to look into svg paths (http://www.w3schools.com/svg/) you can use an online application (http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1771/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html) or an application like inkscape to create or edit sag's

Pro:

- this loads fast by the browser (better than images)
- you can apply effects and animations to it
- scales very good

Contra:

- when another developer looks at your code he may not see what you are doing there

  - add clear comments
  - or save it to a .svg file and add it like a normal image

any more questions? I'll try to create an example for you.

edit: when I re-read your question I noticed that you need it at the bottom, try using

```
div#yourDiv{
     position:relative;
}
div#yourDiv:after{
     content:"";
     position:absolute;
     width:100px;
     left:0;
     height:100px;
     bottom: -100px;
     background: url(kiwi.svg);
}
```